# Shiny Date Picker opening below the menu bar

Tags: r, shiny

I've made a app where you need to choose a date. When you use the date picker it will show up behind the menu bar, and hide important information.

[image: Correct way]

You can see the top line of the date picker and can see which month your in and browse fast between months.

Now, if the date is placed a bit lower, the menu-bar will hide the top of the date picker and show up such as this:

[image: No date picker here]

How can I avoid this? I've added code that replicates the error with the second date chooser below

```
# Setup 

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
      dateRangeInput('dateRange1',
                     label = 'Period 1, Current Month',
                     start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date() + 9,
                     separator = ";", 
                     weekstart = 1), # This opens correct
      dateRangeInput('dateRange1',
                     label = 'Period 1, Current Month',
                     start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date() + 9,
                     separator = ";", 
                     weekstart = 1) # This does NOT open correct!
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `z-index` of the `div` holding the data picker is set to 820 using inline CSS. This does not seem enough to put it above everything else so you could increase it using a `style` tag.

You could for example add:

```
tags$style(HTML(".datepicker {z-index:99999 !important;}"))
```

after the `dateRangeInput`.

Answer (score 1):

I've believe the issue is due to the bootstrap css dynamically altering classes depending on where objects are positioned on the page.

In your original example the two date range pickers have been assigned slightly different classes..

**class=“datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-bottom”**

and

**class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top"**

By simply rearranging the order of the objects on the page I have caused *datepicker-orient-bottom* to be applied to both.

If this order of objects doesn't suit you'll have to define your own css.

My reordered example..

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
    ## Sidebar content
    dashboardSidebar(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-server-account { display: none; }'))),
    sidebarMenu(
        dateRangeInput('dateRange1', 
                       label = 'Period 1, Current Month',
                       start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date() + 9,
                       separator = ";", 
                       weekstart = 1),
        dateRangeInput('dateRange2', 
                       label = 'Period 2, Current Month',
                       start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date() + 9,
                       separator = ";", 
                       weekstart = 1), 
        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
        menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
),
dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        # First tab content
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                fluidRow(
                    box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

                    box(
                        title = "Controls",
                        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                    )
                )
        ),

        # Second tab content
        tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
                h2("Widgets tab content")
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
set.seed(122)
histdata <- rnorm(500)

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: On reflection I may have mis-read your issue. I thought you wanted a solution whereby datepicker-orient-bottom would be applied to the class of both objects. Please ignore. :)