# How to bring Date Range picker to the front in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have updated the latest version of R and Shiny. In this latest version the Date Range picker goes behind the heading on the page making it difficult to get to the year (see pick). I need to bring the widger in frontenter image description here

I think some css code needs to be added. Any help will be appreciated[image]

```
Here's a snippet of the code
```

tabPanel("Rank IPL Batsmen",

```
                                                                  h4('Rank IPL Batsmen'),
                                                                  sidebarPanel(
                                                                      uiOutput("dateRange5"),
                                                                      sliderInput("minMatches", "Matches played",
                                                                                  min = (helper(IPLTeamNames,"./ipl/iplBattingBowlingDetails")[[3]]),
                                                                                  max = (helper(IPLTeamNames,"./ipl/iplBattingBowlingDetails")[[4]]),
                                                                                  value =round(((helper(IPLTeamNames,"./ipl/iplBattingBowlingDetails")[[3]]) + (helper(IPLTeamNames,"./ipl/iplBattingBowlingDetails")[[4]]))/2)
                                                                                      ),
                                                                          uiOutput("Mode")

                                                                      ),
```

Ganesh

Comment: Could you provide some example code?

Comment: See line 187 in https://github.com/tvganesh/gpp2021-7/blob/main/ui.R

Comment: Added code in the  description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CSS z-index property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to control the stack order the HTML elements, try something like:

`uiOutput("dateRange5", style = "z-index: 1;")`

Comment: More detailed explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549289/shiny-date-picker-opening-below-the-menu-bar