# Shiny Date Picker opening below the navbarpage menu

Tags: shiny, datepicker

How Can i Fixed this issue in navbarpage regarding this example [of dashboardPage][1]

Where could i exactly put the tag$style in my navbarpage in rshiny si that the date Picker will come in front?

````
tags$style(HTML(".datepicker {z-index:99999 !important;}"))```


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549289/shiny-date-picker-opening-below-the-menu-bar
````

Comment: can't you use any of the answers offered in the link provided?

Comment: I have just find a solution for it. Thanks.